# A simple link to make a search of a keyword with Google

Tags: php, html

In a PHP page I need a simple link to make a Google search with a keyword. The ones I used in past don't work anymore:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?q=test
https://www.google.com/?q=test
```

The browser open the Google website but it doesn't show the results until the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should do the trick:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=test
```

You could also check http://www.googleguide.com/linking.html for more information about linking to google results.